# How to add array map to firestore database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to add json data to the firestore database through node, like below json data

```
[
  {
    "itemID": "NOODLES_V_101",
    "itemName": "Hakka Noodles",
    "itemPriceHalf": 80,
    "itemPriceFull": 130,
    "hasImage": false,
    "itemCategory": "noodles_v",
    "itemType": "v" 
  },
  {
    "itemID": "NOODLES_V_102",
    "itemName": "Shezwan Noodles",
    "itemPriceHalf": 80,
    "itemPriceFull": 130,
    "hasImage": false,
    "itemCategory": "noodles_v",
    "itemType": "v"
  },
]
```

I want to add firestore array map through the JSON, how should I do that?
The type of array map I want is shown in screenshot below

[image]

If anymore information is required please let me know

The code I am using to add json data to the firestore is below
files.forEach(function(file) {
var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

```
var menu = require("./files/" + file);

menu.forEach(function(obj) {
  firestore
    .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
    .doc(obj.itemID)
    .set(obj)
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document written");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
});
```

});
I have json files which are being added as firestore data through the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is just an array of objects, similar to what you have already shown above.

```
firebase
    .collection("your-collection")
    .doc("your-document")
    .set({
        ids: [
            { id: "1" },
            { id: "2" }
        ]
    })
```

Comment: Doug, I tried as you said, but it didn't worked, please check the question above which i have edited with some more code information

Comment: Could you try using `.set()` instead of `.add()`? .With `add()` a new document will be created with an ID automatically generated.